# Search in Array inside Array in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can view/test the direct link to the page here: [**Search Page Here**](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/search.htm)

I have the following JQuery:
    $(function() {
        $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
            var r_id = $("input[@name=sc]:checked").attr('id');
            //alert(r_id);

```
        if (r_id == "bName") {
            //enable By Name drop down
            $(".dName").prop('disabled', false);
            //disable By Specialty and By Status drop down
            $(".dSpecialty").prop('disabled', true);
            $(".dStatus").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if (r_id == "bSpecialty") {
            //enable By Specialty drop down
            $(".dSpecialty").prop('disabled', false);
            //disable By Name and By Status drop down
            $(".dName").prop('disabled', true);
            $(".dStatus").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if (r_id == "bStatus") {
            //enable By Status drop down
            $(".dStatus").prop('disabled', false);
            //disable By Name and By Specialty drop down
            $(".dName").prop('disabled', true);
            $(".dSpecialty").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
    $('.sButton').click(function() {
        var dNameVal = $(".dName").val();
        var dSpecialtyVal = $(".dSpecialty").val();
        var dStatusVal = $(".dStatus").val();
        if ((dNameVal != "#" && $('.dName').is(':enabled')) || (dSpecialtyVal != "#" && $('.dSpecialty').is(':enabled')) || (dStatusVal != "#" && $('.dStatus').is(':enabled'))) {
            //alert ("good");
            $('.displayresult').css('display','block');

            if ($('.dName').is(':enabled')) {
                document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')].firstName;
                document.getElementById('last').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')].lastName;
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')].status;
                document.getElementById('specialty').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')].specialty;
                document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')].address;
                document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML = phyList[$(".dName").find('option:selected').attr('id')].phone;
            }
            if ($('.dSpecialty').is(':enabled')) {
                var fname = "";
                var lname = "";
                var stats = "";
                var spec = "";
                var addr = "";
                var phonen = "";
                for (test=0;test<=phyList.length-1;test++) {
                    i = phyList[test].specialty; //get all specialty in the array
                    //alert(i); //test alert
                    if (i == $(".dSpecialty").find('option:selected').attr('id')) { //if what's in the phyList array matches selection
                        fname = fname + phyList[test].firstName + "<br>";
                        lname = lname + phyList[test].lastName + "<br>";
                        stats = stats + phyList[test].status + "<br>";
                        spec = spec + phyList[test].specialty + "<br>";
                        addr = addr + phyList[test].address + "<br>";
                        phonen = phonen + phyList[test].phone + "<br>";

                        document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = fname;
                        document.getElementById('last').innerHTML = lname;
                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = stats;
                        document.getElementById('specialty').innerHTML = spec;
                        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = addr;
                        document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML = phonen;
                        //alert ("ok");
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($('.dStatus').is(':enabled')) {
                var fname = "";
                var lname = "";
                var stats = "";
                var spec = "";
                var addr = "";
                var phonen = "";
                for (test=0;test<=phyList.length-1;test++) {
                    i = phyList[test].status; //get all specialty in the array
                    //alert(i); //test alert
                    if (i == $(".dStatus").find('option:selected').attr('id')) { //if what's in the phyList array matches selection
                        fname = fname + phyList[test].firstName + "<br>";
                        lname = lname + phyList[test].lastName + "<br>";
                        stats = stats + phyList[test].status + "<br>";
                        spec = spec + phyList[test].specialty + "<br>";
                        addr = addr + phyList[test].address + "<br>";
                        phonen = phonen + phyList[test].phone + "<br>";

                        document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = fname;
                        document.getElementById('last').innerHTML = lname;
                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = stats;
                        document.getElementById('specialty').innerHTML = spec;
                        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = addr;
                        document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML = phonen;
                        //alert ("ok");
                        document.getElementById('errorst').innerHTML = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('errorst').innerHTML = "<i>No match found</i>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            alert ("not good");
            //display the last successful result search
        }
    });
});
```

The following HTML code:

```
<table border=0 cellPadding=10 cellSpacing=10>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=radio name=sc id=bName class=searchCriteria checked /> By Name:</td>
        <td>
            <select class="dName" name="dName">
                <option SELECTED value="#" DISABLED>========================</option>
                <option id="0" value="amensah">Abbey-Mensah, Michael</option>
                <option id="1" value="acharya">Acharya, Niraj</option>
                <option id="2" value="achonu">Achonu, Geoffrey C.</option>
                <option id="3" value="agustin">Agustin, Erie</option>
                <option id="4" value="agyemang">Agyemang, Kuragu</option>
                <option id="5" value="jahmed">Ahmed, Jahid</option>
                <option id="6" value="fahmad">Ahmad, Faqir</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><span id="errorna"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=radio name=sc id=bSpecialty class=searchCriteria /> By Specialty:</td>
        <td>
            <select class="dSpecialty" name="dSpecialty" DISABLED>
                <option SELECTED value="#" DISABLED>========================</option>
                <option id="Anesthesiology" value="Anesthesiology">Anesthesiology</option>
                <option id="Cardiovascular Disease" value="Cardiovascular Disease">Cardiovascular Disease</option>
                <option id="Dentistry" value="Dentistry">Dentistry</option>
                <option id="Dermatology" value="Dermatology">Dermatology</option>
                <option id="Emergency Medicine" value="Emergency Medicine">Emergency Medicine</option>
                <option id="Family Practice" value="Family Practice">Family Practice</option>
                <option id="Gastroenterology" value="Gastroenterology">Gastroenterology</option>
                <option id="Geriatric Medicine" value="Geriatric Medicine">Geriatric Medicine</option>
                <option id="Hematology" value="Hematology">Hematology</option>
                <option id="Internal Medicine" value="Internal Medicine">Internal Medicine</option>
                <option id="Interventional Cardiology" value="Interventional Cardiology">Interventional Cardiology</option>
                <option id="Medicine" value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
                <option id="Obstetrics" value="Obstetrics">Obstetrics</option>
                <option id="Oral & Maxillofacial Surgery" value="Oral & Maxillofacial Surgery">Oral & Maxillofacial Surgery</option>
                <option id="Orthopedic Surgery" value="Orthopedic Surgery">Orthopedic Surgery</option>
                <option id="Otolaryngology" value="Otolaryngology">Otolaryngology</option>
                <option id="Pathology" value="Pathology">Pathology</option>
                <option id="Pediatrics" value="Pediatrics">Pediatrics</option>
                <option id="Physical Medicine & Rehab" value="Physical Medicine & Rehab">Physical Medicine & Rehab</option>
                <option id="Plastic Surgery" value="Plastic Surgery">Plastic Surgery</option>
                <option id="Podiatry" value="Podiatry">Podiatry</option>
                <option id="Psychiatry" value="Psychiatry">Psychiatry</option>
                <option id="Psychotherapy" value="Psychotherapy">Psychotherapy</option>
                <option id="Pulmonary Medicine" value="Pulmonary Medicine">Pulmonary Medicine</option>
                <option id="Rad. Nuclear Medicine" value="Rad. Nuclear Medicine">Rad. Nuclear Medicine</option>
                <option id="Radiology" value="Radiology">Radiology</option>
                <option id="Surgery" value="Surgery">Surgery</option>
                <option id="Urology" value="Urology">Urology</option>
                <option id="Vascular" value="Vascular">Vascular</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><span id="errorsp"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=radio name=sc id=bStatus class=searchCriteria /> By Status:</td>
        <td>
            <select class="dStatus" name="dStatus" DISABLED>
                <option SELECTED value="#" DISABLED>========================</option>
                <option id="Active" value="active">Active</option>
                <option id="Allied Health Staff" value="allied">Allied Health Staff</option>
                <option id="Consulting" value="consulting">Consulting</option>
                <option id="Courtesy" value="courtesy">Courtesy</option>
                <option id="Leave of Absence" value="loa">Leave of Absence</option>
                <option id="Primary Provider" value="primary">Primary Provider</option>
                <option id="Provisional" value="provisional">Provisional</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><span id="errorst"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colSpan=2 align=right><input type=button value="Search" class="sButton" name="sButton" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class=displayresult>
    <table border=0 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0 width=100%>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Specialty</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Phone Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first" id="first" name="first"></td>
            <td class="last" id="last" name="last"></td>
            <td class="status" id="status" name="status"></td>
            <td class="specialty" id="specialty" name="specialty"></td>
            <td class="address" id="address" name="address"></td>
            <td class="phone" id="phone" name="phone"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The following CSS code:

```
.displayresult {
    display: none;
}
```

Now if you check the JS code, the following Doctor has multiple specialties:

```
...
{
"firstName": "Ahmad",
"lastName": "Faqir",
"status": "Provisional",
"specialty": ["Internal Medicine", "Pediatrics"],
"address": "test test, Brooklyn NY 11218",
"phone": "456.673.4389"
}
...
```

**How do I change the JQuery function to ensure he shows up for both choices, when the user selects "Internal Medicine" OR "Pediatrics" as a specialty?**

Also the following JS isn't working:

```
...
                if (i == $(".dStatus").find('option:selected').attr('id')) { //if what's in the phyList array matches selection
                    fname = fname + phyList[test].firstName + "<br>";
                    lname = lname + phyList[test].lastName + "<br>";
                    stats = stats + phyList[test].status + "<br>";
                    spec = spec + phyList[test].specialty + "<br>";
                    addr = addr + phyList[test].address + "<br>";
                    phonen = phonen + phyList[test].phone + "<br>";

                    document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = fname;
                    document.getElementById('last').innerHTML = lname;
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = stats;
                    document.getElementById('specialty').innerHTML = spec;
                    document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = addr;
                    document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML = phonen;
                    //alert ("ok");
                    document.getElementById('errorst').innerHTML = "";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('errorst').innerHTML = "<i>No match found</i>";
                }
            }
...
```

It always displays the *No match found* message regardless of whether a match is found or not.

**How do I make it so only displays the message when no match is found?**

Comment: What is the `if` expression in the last block of code? It got cut off.

Comment: _Also the following JQuery isn't working:_ this is not a jQuery but a raw JS.

Comment: @RickViscomi It was part of the original code and didn't want to expand it. But of your request I added it now.

Comment: @ArthurHalma Thanks, I corrected the verbiage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you could be having a problem is because you never declare i. Your for loop should start like so:

```
for (test=0;test<=phyList.length-1;test++) {
   var i = phyList[test].specialty; //get all specialty in the array
```

This is going to give you an array if there are multiple specialities so you should use a second for loop to go through your specialities.

```
for ( var iVar; iVar < i.length; iVar++ )
{
    if (i[iVar] == $(".dStatus").find('option:selected').attr('id')) { //if what's in the phyList array matches selection
        //code
    }
}
```

This should check all specialities of each doctor.

As not all specialities are added as arrays, you'll need to include the original if statement outside of the for loop. Here's a working jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/k7jhq/

Comment: Should I add another FOR LOOP under the "i"? Would it be possible to show me the example? I will try to edit mine in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: I am only trying to print the line once. So If Pediatrics is chosen I would want the doctor's name listed once.

Comment: Ah I missed that, then yes, a second for loop would be better, set your index to be over your maximum value when you find a match.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5mBvq/ (Now it only shows the doctor with the two Specialties but skips the others) Please check and let me know how to fix it. If Pediatrics is chose from Specialty, it should display three doctors.

Comment: Glad to help, you could tidy up the code by declaring all the specialities as arrays and only having the for loop, but it's functional now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a simplified example of what you can do using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to find the right objects.

```
// value of dropdown
var spe = $('#test').val();

var matchedPhy = $.map(phyList, function (v, i) {
    // return object if string matches or string is in array
    return v.specialty == spe || $.inArray(spe,v.specialty) > -1 ? v: null;
});

if(matchedPhy.length){
    // found some results
}else{
    // found no results
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AVU5N/

Comment: it looks GREAT and exactly what I want it to do... But for the third doctor can i just show "Pediatric" rather than both specialties? And how would i incorporate it in here: jsfiddle.net/5mBvq

Comment: You can show whatever you want.. I just looped through to show the object's key/values.. but you can customize them all to display what you want.

Comment: @SiKni8 here's an example of how you can control the output [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RXe9X/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time... But unfortunately I can only choose one correct answer. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to assist me...